# Can't enable virtualization

Tags: windows-8, android-emulator, virtualization, intel, haxm

I'm trying to get my Android Emulator running faster,
but i can't enable virtualization. When i open 
bios, it saids that it is enabled, but when i run Intel Processor Identification Utility, it display "Supporting advanced intel processor technologies: Intel(R) Virtualization Technology: no" . But when i look at the page about my processor on intels page, it saids that my processor supports virtualization

About my machine:

- Dell Studio 1749
- 4 GB Ram
- Intel Core i5-450M CPU ([specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/49022/Intel-Core-i5-450M-Processor-3M-cache-2_40-GHz))
- Windows 8 64bit

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! 
In Windows 8 i need to disable Hyper-V.. I don't know why.

Comment: If we disable Hyper-V, we couldn't use WP8 Emulator, it's really frustrating. :(

Comment: Yeah.. Really.. What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V uses the VT resources and if they are already being used by another process then they will not be available for HAXM to use.